# How to sample records from a database without repeating?

Tags: r

Good afternoon , my problem is as follow :

I have a database called friends :

```
friends <- data_frame(
  name = c("Nicolas", "Thierry", "Bernard", "Jerome", "peter", "yassine", "karim"),
  age = c(27, 26, 30, 31, 31, 38, 39),
  height = c(180, 178, 190, 185, 187, 160, 158),
  married = c("M", "M", "N", "N", "N", "M", "M")
)

i <- Intervals(
  matrix(
    c(0,5000,  
      0,5000,
      7000,10000,  
      7000,10000,
      7000,10000,
      10000,15000,  
      10000,15000
    ),
    byrow = TRUE,
    ncol = 2
  ),
  closed = c( TRUE, TRUE ),
  type = "R"
)
```

I need to create a function that take this database as argument.

The function will sample a row ( for example the fourth row just one time , the function will not select this row for other executions ) , then it will operates some traitements.

```
sampling_fct<-function(data){

data[sample(nrow(data), 1), ]

# sample a given row only one time  

}
```

If we have 5 rows , selections should be like :

data[3]

data[2]

data[5]

data[4]

data[1]

where data = friends.

I shouldn't have duplicated results [like these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5sOW.png).

I wish my question is clear.

Thanks to you before !

Comment: So the function should sample a row at random just once? Can the function edit the underlying `data.frame`?

Comment: Dunois , yes the function should select just one row ( in each excecution) for just once.  -- Sampling Without Replacement

Comment: Why not ```row_sample <- sample(nrow(data))``` also, please do not post data as images - you should copy the data into here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are looking for something like this:

```
#Input data
friends <- data.frame(
  name = c("Nicolas", "Thierry", "Bernard", "Jerome", "peter", "yassine", "karim"),
  age = c(27, 26, 30, 31, 31, 38, 39),
  height = c(180, 178, 190, 185, 187, 160, 158),
  married = c("M", "M", "N", "N", "N", "M", "M")
)

#Random row draw function
#Takes the dataframe and a list of forbidden row values as input
tst_func <- function(data, verbot_list){
  if(length(verbot_list) == nrow(data)){
    stop("ERROR: no possible rows left to be sampled.")
  } else {
    repeat{
      curnum <- as.integer(sample(1:nrow(data), 1))
      if(!(curnum %in% verbot_list)){
        break
      }
    }
    verbot_list <- c(verbot_list, curnum)
    #data[curnum, ]
    return(list(data[curnum, ], verbot_list))
  }
}

#Initialization of empty list in parent env. that maintains rows that cannot be drawn from anymore
rm_list <- c()

#Example run
tstval <- tst_func(friends, rm_list)

tstrow <- tstval[[1]]
tstrow
#      name age height married
# 1 Nicolas  27    180       M

rm_list <- tstval[[2]]
rm_list
# [1] 1
```

If all possible rows have been been drawn (randomly):

```
rm_list
# [1] 1 5 3 4 6 2 7
```

The function exits with an error:

```
tstval <- tst_func(friends, rm_list)
# Error in tst_func(friends, rm_list) : 
#   ERROR: no possible rows left to be sampled.
```

(To repeatedly draw random rows, just implement the function within a loop.)

Comment: Yes it's exactly what i'm looking for.  Thank you a lot for your precious help !

Comment: Please note that if you improperly modify `rm_list` maintained in the parent environment, the function will fail to execute or return duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that you sample a given row only once, you can use `sample(replace=FALSE)` (re: [R Examples of sample()](http://www.rexamples.com/14/Sample())).

Given your dataset, consider using:

```
friends <- data.frame(
      name = c("Nicolas", "Thierry", "Bernard", "Jerome", "peter", "yassine", "karim"),
      age = c(27, 26, 30, 31, 31, 38, 39),
      height = c(180, 178, 190, 185, 187, 160, 158),
      married = c("M", "M", "N", "N", "N", "M", "M")
    )

sampling_fct<-function(data){

  data[sample(nrow(data), size = 6, replace = TRUE), ]

}

mylist <- list(friends, friends, friends)

mylist_sampled <- lapply(mylist,sampling_fct)
```

Comment: thank you but I'm not wanting duplicate results , look the picture in my post to understand :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5sOW.png

Comment: The OP wants all previously sampled rows to be excluded from the sampling pool.

Comment: Your solution avoids duplicates for a given sample , but my sample will contain only one record so size=1 .